# token is not verifying on bsc scan

Tags: solidity, bsc, contract-verification

i am using remix to deploy this token. it compile and deployed to mainnet/testnet using remix. but when i try to verify the source code it gives me this error.

```
     Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (Expected library(ies) but one or more was not provided)
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : BABYCUBAN, BABYCUBANDividendTracker, Context, DividendPayingToken, DividendPayingTokenInterface, DividendPayingTokenOptionalInterface, ERC20, IERC20, IERC20Metadata, IUniswapV2Factory, IUniswapV2Pair, IUniswapV2Router01, IUniswapV2Router02, IterableMapping, Ownable, SafeMath, SafeMathInt, SafeMathUint
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
```

what am i missing.

here is the full code https://github.com/coderbang1/code-cuban/blob/main/code-cuban

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this? It looks like you have the same problem thats described here https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-verify-tiki-forks-on-etherscan-bscscan/12599

Comment: yes i got the library part but multiple files confused me...can you suggest me how to do this for this token?

Comment: Well you got the iterableMapping library as well, i think what happened for you is the exact thing described in this topic isnt it?